# Get current time of video playing in AVPlayer ios

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

When I am playing video using AVPlayer then i am not able to get current item when video starts playing. I have used below code to get current time.
Please help me to resolve below issue. Thanks in advance

```
let item1 = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSURL(string:path))
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item1)

layer?.player = player;
player?.play

let currentItem:AVPlayerItem = player!.currentItem
let currentTime:NSTimeInterval = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())
```

Comment: Check whether your video is playing...  you'd better post more code

Comment: @AlexChan How can i determine whether video is playing or not

Comment: I don't know this is OK :`let item1 = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSURL(string:path))`. but try this: `let item1 = AVPlayerItem(URL:xxx)`

Comment: In order to check if the video is playing you have to add an observer and then check for the rate (rate == 0.0 video is not playing, 1.0 normal playback, -1.0 reverse playback).

Answer (score 10):

You can change it to an Int, Double, or Float. Whichever you like.

```
let t1 = Float(self.player.currentTime().value)
let t2 = Float(self.player.currentTime().timescale)
let currentSeconds = t1 / t2
```